# editing textfield on a locked sortable layer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to

1. edit a textfield on every sortable;
2. prevent some sortable layers from being dragged.

To prevent dragging (#2), I follow the [instructions from the api](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel):

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ cancel: ".donotmoveme" });
```

But, now the textfield on that unsortable layer can't be edited anymore.

Here is a demo of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/D6yzf/

And here is the relevant code:
HTML:

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class='donotmoveme'>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    'cancel':'.donotmoveme'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i'm not sure the exact cause of the problem, but here is a solution  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/4BgK3/)

You could add a handle that will be used for dragging the elements inside the sortable.

Also, if you've seen , when you specify the cancel property it's actually not  `.notme` input text that is being disabled but the other input that is being disabled.

.js

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        cancel:'.notme',
    handle:".sort"
});
```

.html

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div>
        <input type="text">
            <span class="sort">sort handle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="notme">
        <p>not me</p>

        <input type="text">
            <span class="sort">sort handle</span>
    </div>
</div>
```